# Lost Pictures Folder Icon

Tags: icons, folder

I have involuntary renamed Pictures Folder. I have lost the custom icon on it. Is it possible to recover the Pictures icon once the folder is renamed again to Pictures?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to recover the Pictures icon once the folder is renamed
>   again to Pictures?

Yes, just rename it back to Pictures.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides Paulo's solution, you can make any folder become the folder of Photos, Documents, Downloads, etc. Just change the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file according to your needs.
This is how the file looks like

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```